# What is the difference creating an instance of a class with and without the correct parameter of __init__()?

Tags: python, class, oop, initialization, instance

I printed out both instances, the correct one starts with <**main**.Book , and the wrong parameter of **init**() starts with class '**main**.Book'. May I know what is the difference/purpose, please?

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

book1 = Book("Lion King") 
book2 = Book  #Doesn't have the right parameter as title not included? 

print(b1)  #<__main__.Book object at 0x10cad5c10>
print(b2)  #<class '__main__.Book'>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`book1 = Book("Lion King")` creates an `instance` of `class Book` because **`Book("Lion King")` is the constructor of the class Book.**

`book2 = Book` assigns `book2` the `class Book`, because **Book is a class and NOT a method**

Comment: Does that mean I am assigning the class Book to a book2 variable? May I know do people do that for any purpose?

Comment: Yes, you're doing exactly that. If after `book2 = Book` you type `book3 = book2("Harry Potter")`, book3 will be a new `Book object` because book2 is assigned to `class Book`. As for the reason, I haven't encountered any valid reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "book1" is an initialized class that is stored at 0x10cad5c10 in your RAM. The variable "book2" is not an initialized class but rather an alias. You can initialize it like this:

```
aBook = book2("a Title")
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the first condition got initialized and stored at some address in your RAM, whereas in the 2nd case it does not got initialized - it is only aliasing.

The second case just makes the object and gives a value for that instance.